# VS Code error details on popup is not working

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-code

[VS Code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2ecj.png)

The code has an error ("<endl;"). here is a red underline for the error. Previously when I take my cursor in the underline, A popup opens and it shows why it's underlined. And the suggestion to fix it. But it's not shoeing that popup now.

-> I've IntelliSense added.
-> Squiggle is also enabled in both User and Workspace settings.

How do I get that popup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your VSCode `settings.json` file, try adding the following:

```json
{
    "editor.hover.enabled": true
}
```

Comment: Please add more details about what is this? and why this option resolve this issue?